# Blazor Select bound value doesn't change when option value is changed dynamically

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly

Working in Blazor Server, I have a select box where the options are dynamically generated from user input in a parent component:

```
<select @bind="Item.Target">
@foreach (var targetOption in AvailableTargets)
{
    <option value="@targetOption">@targetOption</option>
}
</select>
```

The `AvailableTargets` property is a parameter on the component passed in from the parent:

```
<MyChildComponent Item="@CurrentItem" AvailableTargets="@AllTargets"></MyChildComponent>
```

The value of `Item.Target` is *not* updated when `AvailableTargets` is updated on the parent component, even if the currently selected option changes. The option *will* change on the UI, but the binding doesn't update and stays at its original value.

Does anyone know of any way to get this working, or am I stuck putting a method on the child component to re-do the options/binding every time an update is made in the parent?

Comment: This binding won't update the parent UI anyway. What is your exact question? Is changing AllTargets a necessary step?

Comment: You are close to an [MRE], finish it.